# TortoiseGit and changelists

Tags: git, tortoisegit, changelist

we are migrating from subversion to git and one of our git clients is Tortoise.

With TortoiseSvn I usually sorted my modified files into changelists. The TortoiseGit documentation states in chapter 2.26 that this should also be possible with TortoiseGit.

Unfortunately I cannot find this feature in my installation of TortoiseGit:

- TortoiseGit 2.10.0.2 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)
- git version 2.24.0.windows.2 (C:\Program Files\Git\bin; C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\; C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig)

Is there any magic to activate it?

Regards
  Michael

Comment: I wonder if you’re referring to the log? Or maybe diffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the [*figure* 2.26](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-changelists.html#tgit-dug-commit-dia-changelist), and those changelists can be created from the commit dialog box, by right-clicking the file in the commit dialog box:

[image: Move to changelist]

Comment: Yes, _figure_ 2.26 and YES there it is hidden one level below where I expected it.
Thx!